# WSUS Updates not coming from WSUS Server

Tags: wsus, windows-update

We have a few thousand PCs and laptops, all on Windows 8.1
The WSUS server and DCs are 2012r2. 
The problem I am having, even though the group policies all direct clients to http://wsusserver:8530 and I have checked the registry is this:

Clients eventually get updates (from the web) and they finally install. But it takes a few days as our firewall person has throttled Windows updates with a traffic shaper to be 1% of our bandwidth. Don't agree with that low of a number, but it shouldn't be an issue, as the clients all should be coming to the WSUS server.  This is really impacting trying to image a lot of PCs quickly.

In the windowsupdate.log on clients, it clearly shows the WSUS server. But it takes 24-48 hours to actually get updates on newly installed PCs. Something isn't right.

Comment: Is your WSUS actually configured to cache updates and distribute them? It's been a while since I've managed a WSUS server, but I seem to recall that they can be configured in one of two modes: One where updates are approved on WSUS but clients still download from the web, and one where updates are approved on WSUS *and* clients download the update directly from the WSUS server.

Comment: You say that clients eventually get updates from the web but the log shows them communicating with WSUS. How did you confirm that they were getting updates from the web?

Comment: well, it takes literally 24-48 hours for them to update, and I know our Internet is throttled to 1% of a 50MB connection for Windows updates. So, I made that assumption. If they were accessing the WSUS server, at least at a 100MB connection, there's no way they would take so long, is my assumption.  I know I have not verified that, but can't imagine them taking so long if using the WSUS server

Comment: OK, but that's an assumption, not a verification. What does the Windows Update log on an affected client show?